# How to access a Class in the default package from a sub package Class in Flash AS3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, class, object, flash-cs5

I got error message when trying to access a class in the default package from the class in its sub package. Can any one help me to sort this out.

FYI, my package structure is A -> B. I meant folder 'A' as default package and 'B' as sub package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is you can't. That's why Flash Builder gives you a warning when you create a class in the default package.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a object of Class A, and call class instance method, from its object.

```
var classAObj:A = new A();
classObj.MethodA();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Sorry I was wrong in describing my problem. Now I edited that clear. please see if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is for class B to extend class A. That would look something like this in your code:

```
package main
{
    class B extends A
    {
        // Code here...
    }
}
```

Having code inside packages does not in general affect functionality, it's more an organizational tool. (Except for the `internal` keyword.)

Comment: Thanks for your time. Sorry I was wrong in describing my problem. Now I edited that clear. please see if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

how about **private**, **protected** and **public** ? I could not see any explanation in the other answers so here it is.

```
class A
{
    private var _password:String;
    public var username:String;
    protected var serverURL:String;

    public function login():void
    {
         // some code
         callServerForLogin();
    }

    protected function callServerForLogin():void
    { 
        // some code
    }
 }

 class B extends A
 {
      public function B()
      {
           var parentPassword = super._password;  
           // FAILS because private and accessible only inside class A

           var parentUsername = super.username 
           // all ok in here, public property

           var parentServerURL = super.serverURL;
           // all ok, because it is protected

           // also we can call super.login(); or super.callServerForLogin();

      }

      // IMPORTANT we are also allowed to override public and protected functions
      override public function login():void
      {
          super.login(); 
          // we call the parent function to prevent loosing functionality;  

          Alert.show("Login called from class B");
      }

      override protected function callServerForLogin():void
      {
           super.callServerForLogin();
           // keep also parent logic

           Alert.show("calling protected method from B");
      }
 }


 // ----  Now considering you declare an object of type B you can do the following
 var bObj:B = new B();

 // access public properties and call public functions from both B and A
 bObj.username = "superhero";
 bObj.login();

 // will get compile error for next lines
 bObj.serverURL = "host.port";
 bObj.callServerForLogin();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Sorry I was wrong in describing my problem. Now I edited that clear. please see if you can help me.

Comment: Hi, I am still not sure I understand. can you post some code maybe?